# Extract netcdf4 variable slice by dimension name

Tags: python, netcdf

I have a netCDF file with 4 dimensions. I want to extract a slice from the netCDF file by giving the name of one of the dimensions

I know how to do this by position. E.g.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
hndl_nc = Dataset(path_to_nc)

# Access by slice
hndl_nc.variables['name_variable'][:,5,:,:]
```

Given that I know the names of the dimensions, say `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`. How do I access by dimension name instead of position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html#indexing-with-labeled-dimensions)'s indexing capabilities to access netcdf data by dimension name.

```
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.open_dataset('./foo.nc')
var = ds['name_variable']
# Slice var by Dimension "A" between values 0 and 5
var_slice = var.sel(A=slice(0,5))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the closest current solution is

```py
np.take(nc4_variable[:], dim_ids, axis=dim)
```

or

```py
nc4_variable[:].take(dim_ids, axis=dim)
```

where `dim_ids` is a list or tuple of your slices, and `dim` is the dimension along which you want to slice. Unfortunately, this seems to load the entire dataset first, and there doesn't seem to be a way around that; the `[:]` is necessary. Neglecting it in the first method loads data without adjustments from the `add_offset`, `_FillValue`, etc. parameters; neglecting it in the second method yields an error.

Testing with `%timeit` in ipython confirms major differences between normal slicing and the `np.take` method.

Hope someone comes up with a more complete answer to this; would be very useful for diverse datasets.

Answer (score 0):

So, I might have come up with something that could qualify as a "**solution**".

numpy arrays can evidently be indexed with a singleton list of iterables, e.g.

```
a = np.reshape(range(0,16),(4,4),order='F')
a = a[ [[0,1], [1]] ]
```

returns `a` equal to `array([4,5])`. Another example would be `[[range(3),[1 2],3]]`. These singleton lists are unfurled in the manner of `*subscripts`, as if you had directly queried `a[[0,1],1]` instead of `a[ [[0,1],1] ]`.

So, if you are able to query the position and length of each dimension in your netCDF variable (pretty easy with `nc_fid[var].dimension` and `nc_fid[var].shape`), then you can simply permute a list according to the location of each dimension. For example, if you have data of shape time by lon by lat, and you want **all** longitudes, **all** latitudes, and time index `t=5`, you can use something like

```
order_want = ['lon', 'lat', 'time'] # must figure out dimension names a priori
nlon = nc_fid[var].shape[nc_fid[var].dimensions.index('lon')]
nlat = nc_fid[var].shape[nc_fid[var].dimensions.index('lat')]
ids = [ range(0,nlon), range(0,nlat), 5 ]
ids_permute = [order_want.index(n) for n in nc_fid[var].dimensions] 
ids_query = [l[i] for l,i in zip(ids,ids_permute)]

sliced_data = nc_fid[var][list_query]
```

This requires no a priori knowledge of the dimension position, and **does not** require loading all dimensions of the variable.

Note that after some `%timeit` testing in IPython, it appears there is some special delay for all-integer indexing, e.g. `list_query = [0,0,0,0]` will take **80ms** whereas `list_query = [range(1),0,0,0]` or even `list_query = [[0,1,2,3,4,5],0,0,0]` will take **1ms**. Very mysterious; anyway, evidently you should try to make sure `list_query` is not just a list of integers.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the dimension name and you want to access variable with given dimension instance, you can use boolean indexing. For example:

```
import netCDF4 as nc
era5_file = nc.Dataset(era5_path)   #nc file with time x lon x lat dimension
time_era5 = era5_file.variables['time'][:] # here time_era5 is a variable and 
                                           #  also a dimension
swh_era5 = era5_file.variables['swh'][:]   #swh=significant wave height

swh_era5_specific_hour = swh_era5[time_era5=='specific_hour']
```